# Podio Item exort silence Item.export notifications

Tags: api, notifications, podio

through the API ( https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/export-items-4235696 ) I trigger a batch job but would not like to bother the client with notifications popping up.

Just like we have "silent" for item creation. Do we have a similar setting for batches? I don't think so, can it be added?

Greetings,

PJ

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the API does not support silencing these notifications. I will add a product feature request.